# Salesforce Testing Abstract Class

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, abstract-class, apex, force.com

This might be a noob question however, I am not entirely sure on the procedures to writing unit tests for an abstract class in Salesforce. The class itself has 3 public methods as well as two abstract unimplemented methods. I unfortunately haven't found much help on the topic.

I know abstract classes cannot be constructed which means I can't create an instance of it to test on. Greatly appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 2):

What ultimately worked for me was, I used a class that was already extending the abstract class to call the methods I needed to test. I didn't need a mock object or to create a whole new sub-class to test.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a test subclass which would implement those abstract methods with dummy implementation.
That way, you can instantiate this test class in your test: calling its non-abstract methods will run the production code.

Alternatively, you could look into mocking frameworks: they might even remove the need to subclass the class yourself.